# I started making a math quiz for my friends but the if statements aren't working :(

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a math quiz using trinket.io but it doesn't seem to be working. It is work in progress so I haven't added any questions yet because I got stuck on this :(. Can someone help PLZ

```
print("Math Quiz is a game where you answer math questions to improve you score :)")
print("Are you ready?")
print("y/n")
answer = input()

if input == ("y"):
  print("OK")


elif input != ("y"):
  print("That is not an acceptable answer :(")
```

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69225564/edit) your post and add an example of what you expect to happen and what currently happens. Welcome to stack overflow! (And off of a preliminary skim of your code, I think you would do well to check the difference between `input` and `answer` ;) )

Comment: use  `answer == ("y")`

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly simple, I myself recently had a problem like this lol.    in your code, you said:

```
if input == ("y"):
  print("OK")
```

This code can technically run, but it's not in the proper format.
It calls an input and checks if the input equals 'y'
You need it to check if "answer" = 'y'

The proper way is:

```
if answer == 'y':
  print('ok')
```

In your second script

```
elif input != ("y"):
  print("That is not an acceptable answer :(")
```

Change input to 'answer' and it should work.
Suggestion for inputs:  I recommend doing it like this:

```
input('PLease input: ')
```

Add a ':' after the prompt, then a space, or a new line character.

```
input('Please input:\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You did

```
if input == ("y"):
  print("OK")
```

instead of using the variable

```
if answer == ("y"):
  print("OK")
```